# python 3.2 if-else

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I need help with a python 3.2 if-else statement
 the code is:

```
if gam < 1:
    file = open("data1.dat","w")
    gam = gam2
elif gam == 1:
    file = open("data2.dat","w")
    gam = gam3
elif gam > 1:
    file = open("data3.dat","w")
```

when ran I receive a syntax error point to the colon after if gam < 1
if I remove the colon I receive a syntax error pointing at the word file.

edit:
here is more of the code

```
for o in range (3):
    for i in range (0,len(x)):
        for j in range (0,len(y)):
            a[i][j]=x[i]
            b[i][j]=y[j]

    for i in range (0,len(x)):
        for j in range (0,len(y)):
            u[i][j] = (vinf*a[i][j]*b[i][j]*(4*math.pi*math.pow(3,2)+gamma*(math.pow(a[i][j],2)+math.pow(b[i][j],2))))/(2*math.pi*math.pow(math.pow(a[i][j],2)+math.pow(b[i][j],2),2))
            v[i][j] = (1/2)*vinf*((math.pow(b[i][j],2)*(4*math.pi*math.pow(3,2)+b[i][j]*(math.pow(a[i][j],2)+math.pow(b[i][j],2))))/(math.pi*math.pow(math.pow(a[i][j],2)+math.pow(b[i][j],2),2))-(2*math.pow(3,2))/(math.pow(a[i][j],2)+math.pow(b[i][j],2))+(gamma*math.log1p(math.sqrt(math.pow(a[i][j],2)+math.pow(b[i][j],2))/3))/math.pi+2)
            p[i][j] = 1-(math.pow(u[i][j],2)+math.pow(v[i][j],2))
            s[i][j] = (vinf*b[i][j])*(1-(math.pow(3,2)/(math.pow(a[i][j],2)+math.pow(b[i][j],2)))+(gamma/(2*math.pi))*math.log1p(math.sqrt(math.pow(a[i][j],2)+math.pow(b[i][j],2))/3)


    if gam < 1:
        file = open("data1.dat","w")
        gam = gam2
    elif gam == 1:
        file = open("data2.dat","w")
        gam = gam3
    elif gam > 1:
        file = open("data3.dat","w")
```

edit2: i seemed to be missing a parenthesis  on the s line but i am now getting an error when closing the file

```
if gam < 1:
        file = open("data1.dat","w")
        gam = gam2
    elif gam == 1:
        file = open("data2.dat","w")
        gam = gam3
    elif gam > 1:
        file = open("data3.dat","w")
    file.write('title = "Driven Cavity"\r\n')
    file.write('variables = "x", "y", "u", "v", "p", "s"\r\n')
    file.write('ZONE T="All"\r\n')
    file.write(' I={}'.format(len(x)))
    file.write(' J={}'.format(len(x)))
    file.write(' K=1')
    file.write(' ZONETYPE=Ordered\r\n')
    file.write(' DATAPACKING=POINT\r\n')

    for i in range (0,len(x)):
        for j in range (0,len(y)):
            file.write('{}\t'.format(a[i][j]))
            file.write('{}\t'.format(b[i][j]))
            file.write('{}\t'.format(u[i][j]))
            file.write('{}\t'.format(v[i][j]))
            file.write('{}\t'.format(p[i][j]))
            file.write('{}\t\n'.format(s[i][j])
    file.close()
```

never mind just another parenthesis. been a long day

Comment: ... this would suggest to me that the problem is in the line of code preceding `if gam < 1:`.

Comment: I can't get this to fail (assuming all the `gam` variables are defined). Can you post the error message? or more of the code that comes before?

Comment: Consider refactoring the code. I'm sure you can make it much shorter and have less repeated code.

Comment: paste the code present above the if condition.

Comment: SO is not for "please locate my syntax error".

Answer (score 4):

you missed a closing `)` at the end of the line:

```
s[i][j] = (vinf*b[i][j])*(1-(math.pow(3,2)/(math.pow(a[i][j],2)+math.pow(b[i][j],2)))+(gamma/(2*math.pi))*math.log1p(math.sqrt(math.pow(a[i][j],2)+math.pow(b[i][j],2))/3))
```

Comment: Cheers man, at 4:30pm my head was spinning just looking at the script. I need a beer now.

Answer (score 1):

This specific expression `(math.pow(a[i][j],2)` in the marathon expression just before the `if` statement looks as if it's missing the closing `)`

I.e.,

```
s[i][j] = (vinf*b[i][j])*(1-(math.pow(3,2)/(math.pow(a[i][j],2) + ...
```

should be

```
s[i][j] = (vinf*b[i][j])*(1-(math.pow(3,2)/(math.pow(a[i][j],2)) + ...
```

though it's hard to be certain given the length of the expression and possible grouping desired.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid mis-matched (), {}, [], '', "", etc, errors, use a code editor that indicates the opener when you use a closer, preferably with knowledge of the particular language. Idle's editor does this for Python, Notepad++ for several languages, and several other editors for various languages.

When you get a puzzling SyntaxError that seems wrong (at the location indicated) modify the code somehow and see if the indicator moves. In your original code, if you had put *anything* on the line before the if, such as '1==1', the ^ would have moved to that line instead. Then you would have known that the problem was before the if statement.

Comment: Much better to write code that makes dependence on such tools less crucial. I've never seen such long lines with dense math, that just cries out for mistakes. PEP 8 never seemed that needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to your question, but: your code seems to be doing an awful lot of unnecessary work. I've tried to streamline it a bit.

```
from math import log1p, sqrt, pi
NEWLINE = '\r\n'
header = NEWLINE.join([
    'title = "Driven Cavity"',
    'variables = "x", "y", "u", "v", "p", "s"',
    'ZONE T="All"',
    ' I={} J={} K=1 ZONETYPE=Ordered',
    ' DATAPACKING=POINT',
    ''
])

for o in range(3):
    if gam < 1:    fname = "data1.dat"
    elif gam == 1: fname = "data2.dat"
    else:          fname = "data3.dat"

    with open(fname, "w") as outf:
        outf.write(header.format(len(x), len(y)))

        for _x in x:
            for _y in y:
                _xsq = _x**2
                _ysq = _y**2
                sqsq = (_xsq + _ysq)**2
                chunk = gamma*log1p(sqrt(_xsq+_ysq)/3.)/pi

                u = 0.5*vinf*_x*_y*(36.*pi + gamma*(_xsq+_ysq))/(pi*sqsq)
                v = 0.5*vinf*(2. + _ysq*(36.*pi + _y*(_xsq+_ysq))/(pi*sqsq) - 18./(_xsq+_ysq) + chunk)
                p = 1. - (u**2 + v**2)
                s = vinf*_y*(1. - 9./(_xsq+_ysq) + 0.5*chunk)

                outf.write('{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}{}'.format(_x, _y, u, v, p, s, NEWLINE))
```

Hope this helps.